# Recreate Header from sample with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, boxes

I want to recreate the header from this book:
https://books.google.de/books?id=ybEmCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false
Example images:
[image: Header even pages]
[image: header odd pages]

So on even pages, the chapter number is on the top left corner in a gray box. This is followed by the chapter name.
In contrast to the example here, the headsepline should extend over the whole page, i.e. the line should extend into the inner margin.

On odd pages the section should be shown on the top right corner. Again, the headsepline should extend over the whole page.

My current attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[markcase=noupper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark[section]{chapter}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\Graybox}{\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=[c]{\marginparwidth}\centering,height=8pt, bgcolor=gray}}

\lehead{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    {\Graybox{\color{white}\textsf{\thechapter}}}\hspace*{1em}}%
  \leftmark
}

\rohead{\rightmark}

\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: page 123 fillllll

Comment: `scrlayer-scrpage` is (almost) compatible with `scrpage2`. So you can use the `scrpage2` code of the head from the book (page 134f) and do only the wanted changes like increasing the length of the `headsepline`. You will get warnings if you use obsolete commands. The warning messages should contain information about the corresponding new solution.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the hint! I didn't think that the author would publish the layout directly in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following MWE, a version based on the code of the author of the book, Herbert Voss, you can use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `scrpage2` to get the layout you want.

There are some things you should look at:

With

```
\newlength\fullwidth
\setlength\fullwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\fullwidth{-1in}
\addtolength\fullwidth{-\oddsidemargin}% für die Kopflinie
```

`\fullwidth` the lebgth of the line in the header is calculated (right margin + textwidth), with

```
%\setheadwidth[\marginparsep]{textwithmarginpar} % <====================
%\KOMAoption{headwidth}{textwithmarginpar} % <==========================
```

`\KOMAoption` is the `headwidth` set.  Because we want the line reach the paper end we can not use `textwithmarginpar`, we have to use

```
\KOMAoption{headwidth}{\fullwidth:0mm} % <===========================
```

and the `headsepline` is set with

```
%\setheadsepline[\fullwidth]{0.8pt}  % <================================
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.8pt} % <=====================================
```

With the following MWE

```
% 
%% 
%%  Ein Beispiel der DANTE-Edition
%%  
%%  1. Auflage
%% 
%%  Beispiel 05-02-13 auf Seite 134.
%% 
%%  Copyright (C) 2012 Herbert Voss
%% 
%%  It may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%%  of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%%  of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% 
%%  See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt for details.
%% 
%% 
%% ==== 
% Show page(s) 1,2,3
%% 
%% 
\documentclass[parskip=half,pagesize]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,blindtext,xcolor}
\geometry{%
  showframe, % <========================================================
  paperheight=239mm,  % 
  paperwidth=169mm,   % 
  tmargin=5mm,        % top
  textwidth=124mm,    % 
  textheight=195mm,   % 
  rmargin=22mm,       % right (outer)
  heightrounded,
  includeheadfoot,
  headheight=5mm,     % 
  headsep=8mm,        % 
  foot=18mm,          % 
  marginparsep=2mm,   % 
  marginparwidth=18mm % 
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\s@pt{\hspace{6pt}}
\newcommand\chaptertext{K\s@pt a\s@pt p\s@pt i\s@pt t\s@pt e\s@pt l}
\DeclareRobustCommand\headingfont{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{\begingroup
      \flushright
      {\topskip\z@\null}
      \headingfont\mdseries
      \fontsize{14.4}{5.5pc minus .5pc}\selectfont
      \textbf{\chaptertext}
      \fontsize{36}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont\ \thechapter\kern-2pt
                                                  \par
      \fontsize{28}{24pt}\selectfont
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\flushright
      \rule{0pt}{5pc}\normalfont\headingfont #1
      \end{minipage}%
      \null
      \par\endgroup
      \rule{0pt}{7.5pc}\par}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\newlength\fullwidth
\setlength\fullwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\fullwidth{-1in}
\addtolength\fullwidth{-\oddsidemargin}% für die Kopflinie

%\setlength{\footheight}{51.3pt}  
\usepackage[ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % scrlayer-scrpage scrpage2 <====
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot{}
%\setheadwidth[\marginparsep]{textwithmarginpar} % <====================
%\KOMAoption{headwidth}{textwithmarginpar} % <==========================
\KOMAoption{headwidth}{\fullwidth:0mm} % <===========================
\lehead[\clearscrheadfoot]{\mbox{\headingfont\smash{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\raisebox{-2pt}{\colorbox{blue!80}{\makebox[22mm]{\hfill%
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
      \textcolor{white}{\fontsize{18}{19}\selectfont\thechapter}~\fi%
      \rule[-2.85pt]{2mm}{12mm}}}}}\quad\small\leftmark}}
\rohead[\clearscrheadfoot]{\small\headingfont\rightmark\quad\makebox[22mm]{}}
\lefoot[\clearscrheadfoot]{\small\headingfont\llap{\thepage~\rule[-13mm]{.6pt}{18mm}
  \hspace{1mm}}} 
\rofoot[\clearscrheadfoot]{\small\headingfont~
  \hfill \rlap{\hspace{1mm}\rule[-13mm]{.6pt}{18mm}\ \thepage}}
%\setheadsepline[\fullwidth]{0.8pt}  % <================================
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{0.8pt} % <=====================================
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
   \markright{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\@ne \thesection\quad #1\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Textformatierungen}
\section{Seitenstil}\blindtext\par\blindtext\newpage
\section{baz}   \blindtext[2]\par\blindtext\newpage
\section{foobar}\blindtext[2]\par\blindtext\newpage  \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. If you don't like pararagraph indention you should use paragraph separation. With KOMA-Script you should use option `parskip` to do so. And redefinition if `\@makechapterhead` is also not needed for the example and is not recommended if you use a newer KOMA-Script release. And if the line should be extended into the inner margin `headwidth=paper` should be enough.